# What is the science behind coloured shadows?

Tags: visible-light, polarization, diffraction, spectroscopy, shadow

Why are colour shadows formed? I have three coloured glasses in my house and If I keep my hand in its light path, I am seeing coloured shadows on the **opposite wall**.

[image: colour window]

[image: colour shadow]

Why is this happening?

Also currently only orange and blue shadows are visible (from the bottom and middle window light) . But, if I take my hand a little away from the opposite wall, I could see green shadow as well (from the top window light)

Please answer, this is breaking my head

Comment: Cover two of your three windows and you‘ll quickly find out.

Answer (score 3):

The “white” you see on the wall outside the shadow is the additive color of the three windows. I put “white” between quotation marks because it looks off-white to me, probably due to an imbalance in the colors.

The shadow of your hand is in a different spot for each window, since each window is a separate light source in a separate location.

In the shadow for one of the two windows, the other two still illuminate the wall. Hence the colored shadows.

I have a nice big stack of variously colored filters in my flash photography toolkit. I can get some really nice effects with this kind of color mixing. Same principle, and loads of fun.

A nice explanation on additive (light) vs. subtractive (paint) color here: https://www.diyphotography.net/avoid-colour-banding-using-coloured-gels/